# Separar valores de um multi select em colunas

Tags: sql-server, query, select

em meu sistema, eu tenho um multi select como podem vem na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu faço uma exportação desta variável neste select

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(p.Argautor, ',', ';') AS Argautor
FROM jud_Processos p
LEFT JOIN jud_Comarcas c ON p.ComarcaId = c.ComarcaId
LEFT JOIN jud_Municipios m ON p.Munautor = m.MunicipioId
INNER JOIN jud_Estados e ON e.EstadoId = p.EstadoId
```

os resultados desta variável vem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de saber se é possivel separar esta coluna **Argautor** em varias colunas, como exemplo.

quando **Argautor** for = 0 ter uma coluna chamada **coluna0** e que mostre somente os resultados que são 0, **coluna1**  e que mostre somente os resultados que são 1 assim sucessivamente, gostaria de saber se isto é possível

Comment: Então você quer apenas uma linha e várias colunas?

Comment: sim só que como pode ver na foto em uma linha tem varios valores,
exemplo, a coluna0 só pode aparecer os valores que são 0 não pode mostrar outros valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua tabela parece estar modelada de uma forma complicada demais para o fim desejado. Acredito que uma saída seria ter uma tabela intermediária para guardar os códigos referentes ao cadastro. Apesar disso você pode chegar ao resultado que deseja da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ',' + p.argautor + ',' LIKE '%,0,%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS coluna0,
       CASE WHEN ',' + p.argautor + ',' LIKE '%,1,%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS coluna1,
       CASE WHEN ',' + p.argautor + ',' LIKE '%,2,%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS coluna2,
       ...
       CASE WHEN ',' + p.argautor + ',' LIKE '%,15,%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS coluna15
  FROM jud_Processos p
       LEFT JOIN jud_Comarcas c ON p.ComarcaId = c.ComarcaId
       LEFT JOIN jud_Municipios m ON p.Munautor = m.MunicipioId
       INNER JOIN jud_Estados e ON e.EstadoId = p.EstadoId;
```

Você pode tentar gerar o mesmo resultado dinamicamente, porém a possibilidade de erro é maior.

Comment: cara é isso mesmo que eu queria, está correto, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda